# Ошибка django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pythonanywhere

Я задеплоил свой django app на PythonAnywhere и хочу добавить задачу в `scheduled tasks`. Но при исполнении скрипта даёт ошибку:

```py
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Я пробовал делать то, что мне предлагает сама ошибка. Также пробовал:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE', 'smsreminder.settings')
django.setup()
```

результат — та же ошибка, но уже на `django.setup()`.

---

Мой скрипт в файле, который я хочу запустить:

```py
import datetime
from django_common.auth_backends import User
from reminder.models import Remind
from twilio.base.exceptions import TwilioRestException
from twilio.rest import Client

def my_scheduled_job():
    content = Remind.objects.all()
    account_sid = "--------------------------"
    auth_token = "--------------------------"
    for smscontent in content:
        if smscontent.remind_date == datetime.today().date():
            tempusers = User.objects.filter(username=smscontent.author)
            for recipient in tempusers:
                try:
                    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
                    message = client.messages.create(
                        body="I just want to remind, that you have some task for today {date}: {task}. {time} is the deadline!".format(
                            date=str(smscontent.remind_date),
                            task=str(smscontent.title),
                            time=str(smscontent.remind_time)),
                        to=str(recipient.username),
                        from_="+18568889437")
                    print(message.sid)

                except TwilioRestException:
                    pass
    return
```

Сама ошибка:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/remindmy/sms-reminder/reminder/cron.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django_common.auth_backends import User
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_common/auth_backends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Посоветуйте что-нибудь, пожалуйста.

Comment: это надо разбираться с конфигами PythonAnywhere скорее всего

Answer (score -1):

Создал шаблонный проект что для демонстрации.
В нем скрипт `script.py` для демонстрации как сделать так что бы сеттингс из джанки заработал.

```py
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'reminder.settings')
import django
from django.conf import settings

if not settings.configured:
    django.setup()

from user_management.models import BasicUser


def do_some_stuff():
    print(len(BasicUser.objects.all()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_some_stuff()
```

Весь проект [тут](https://github.com/gad26032/stackOverflow_1309558/blob/master/script.py), можно позапускать

```bsh
$ python script.py
```

только миграции сделать не забудьте.